# Undefined offset even submitting foreach loop into database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-blade

I have the following foreach in my view that i am trying to submit and store into my database. Without any luck. When i try to submit, it is returning an error `Undefined offset: 70`.

This is the controller code:

foreach ($request->useridweek1 as $key => $value){

```
      /*  $str_explode = explode("|",$value);
       $numb = $str_explode[1]; */

       $answer = new Retirement();
       $answer->user_id = $value;
       $answer->amount =  $request->amountweek1[$key];;



       $answer-> save();


  }
```

This is my view file with the foreach loop:

```
@foreach ($request as $item)
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="idweek1">
                <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid" class="form-control" value="{{ $item->user_id}}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="marketers" name="marketers[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $item->marketer}}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $item->target * $item->AmountPbag * $fwek1) - ($item->sales->sum('sales') * $item->AmountPbag  }}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="mar1id" class="form-control" value="{{ $item->target * $item->AmountPbag * $fwek1 - $item->sales->sum('sales') * $item->AmountPbag }}">
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
@endforeach


When i dump dd($request->useridweek1);, i get

array:3 [▼
  70 => "70"
  72 => "72"
  73 => "73"
]


When i dump . dd($request->amount);
array:3 [▼
  0 => "14000"
  1 => "9450"
  2 => "8400"
]
```

Comment: Dump the content of `$request->amount` and `$request->userid` and check if they contains the same amount of keys.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? Which line throws that warning?

Comment: Yes i have dumped the values and they all return they values @KFoobar

Comment: $answer->amount =  $ammt[$key]; This is the line throwing the error @NicoHaase

Comment: And what have you tried to spot the error? What does `$ammt` contain?

Comment: @NicoHaase i have update the foreach in the question...$answer->amount = $request->amount[$key];..this is the line given error now

Comment: And have you checked anywhere for errors? If you loop over one array, why should there be any element with the same index in another array?

Comment: i dont know bro...thats why i am asking for help here

Comment: does any of your looped data contain a key of 70? if so, is that its id (primary key) from the database? which attribute in your html is getting that value? Just to test, you could try deleting that value from your table and seeing if the error continues with a different value

Comment: i have emptied my table but this error still persist @maximus1127

Comment: If your table is empty, what are you looping through?

Comment: i am submiting the value from controller to database..picking values from a table to view now i need to send this values to a new table

Comment: so my immediate response is that you have different keys going through each array. your useridweek is an associative array with named keys, your amount array is a standard array with indexes starting at 0. So the reason you're getting undefined offset is because your amount array is looking for an index of "70" which it's getting from the useridweek array, which doesn't exist. So either change the indexes of the useridweek array or the indexes of the amount array

Comment: @maximus1127 how do i change this pls...can u give a clue or a direction

Comment: it's hard for me to tell just from the code provided. i'm not even sure where $request->useridweek1 is coming from because i don't see that specified in the blade template anywhere.

Comment: $request->useridweek1 is an ID for every of the user...coming from another table

Comment: is it possible for me to have ur skype ID? plss?

Comment: check my bio in my profile

Comment: not able to find it bro

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the code below...incase anyone runs into same problem...using the keys from the foreach and also adding [] to my input names on my blade

```
 foreach ($request->amountweek1 as $key => $value){

               $str_explode = explode("|",$value);
               $numb = $str_explode; 





               $answer = new Retirement();
            $answer->marketer = $request->marketers[$key];
               $answer->amount =  $value;
               $answer->user_id = $request->useridweek1[$key];
               $answer->week = $request->week1;



               $answer-> save();




          }
```